# How can you make an element animate back to original positioning upon screen size reduction?

Tags: css, svg, sass

Hello All^^  I have created a slide animation for an SVG logo that I have designed.  Sliding the image to the left with a key frame animation on screen size using media queries was not difficult.  However, I am unable to get the SVG to slide back to center (original position), via animation or transition delay, etc.  Upon changing back to smaller media query sizes, the SVG simply jumps to its original position(main logo on the page).

I have not been able to find a way to resolve this.  However, a link to a codepen is below.  If you think you may be able to help, I would sincerely appreciate it.  Thanks.

https://codepen.io/shaunbolak/pen/RwWmgVK

```
/* ============================================= */
/*          SVG Keyframes                        */
/* ============================================= */

@keyframes offset {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes mobile-path-fill {
    100% {
        fill: $logo-main-path-color;
    }
}


@keyframes fill-desktop {
    100% {
        fill: $logo-alternate-path-color;
    }
}

@keyframes move-left {
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-118%);
    }
}

/* ============================================= */
/*          Main logo                            */
/* ============================================= */


#logo {
    padding-top: 15px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 350px; 

    @include for-size(desktop-up) {
        animation: move-left 2s forwards;
        padding-top: 20px;
        height: 120px;
        width: 300px;
        transition: width 1s;
    }

    @include for-size(larger-desktop-up) {
        width: 350px;
        transition: width 1s;
    }

    @include for-size(big-desktop-up) {
        width: 400px;
        transition: width 1s;
    }
}


#logoFill {
    fill: $logo-main-fill;
    stroke: $logo-main-fill;

    @include for-size(desktop-up) {
        animation: fill-desktop 1.5s 1.2s forwards;
    }
}

.logo-stroke {
    stroke: $logo-main-path-color;
    stroke-width: 1;
    stroke-dasharray: 325;
    stroke-dashoffset: 325;
    animation: offset 3s linear forwards, mobile-path-fill 1.2s 3s forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
@keyframes move-right {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-118%);
  } to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

And then:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #logo {
    animation: move-right 2s;
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 120px;
    width: 300px;
    transition: width 1s;
  }
}
```

I've checked that and it works well...

Comment: Hi Joseph^^  I really appreciate the reply and the help.  Unfortunately, I am not seeing any difference though : /

Comment: I am completely wrong.  I used a code compare tool, and I had a redundant rule (duplicate rule)  for the svg animation - Your fix works perfectly.  Thank you, kind sir^^